# Python simple socket server - doesnt answer after short time

Tags: python, multithreading, service

Could some one help me with making server on python?
I need recive connection, work with binary data, and send this data to database.
Now im using new thread for each connection, and queue recived data. 20 threads work with this queue and insert data into database.
Im using my simple code:

```
server = socket.socket()
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server.bind(('', 9980))
server.listen(15)

while True:
    ClientThread(socket=server.accept(), dataQueue=dataQueue).start()
```

But after some time server doesnt answer for connection.
May be im doing something wrong?
p.s average load - 100-500 request per minute and less 1kb traffic per client, average proccessor load 2.5% and memory usage 3%

Comment: You have set a quite high number of maximum queued connections to this socket. Read Python docs http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen

If your system is unable to process as much queued connections as you have specified, the queue just fills up and ends up not being processed.